# Setting up Cucumber for Protractor in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I have created a Java Script project in Eclipse to implement Protractor scripts and it works fine. I need to implement Protractor scripts based on Cucumber framework. I have downloaded all required Cucumber plugins (Like Natural, cucumber eclipse plugin) and created a sample test.feature file as follows.

```
Feature: Login Action

Scenario: Successful Login with Valid Credentials
    Given User is on Home Page
    When User Navigate to LogIn Page
    And User enters UserName and Password
    Then Message displayed Login Successfully
```

My question is; in Eclipse, is there anyway to create step definitions.JS file from .feature file? and what configuration changes we should do to execute the test?

Comment: Yes download AngularJS plugin from workplace

Comment: Angular JS plugin is already downloaded. Can you specify what actions we need to do generate step definitions ?